# Environment Texture 360

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, hdri

New to blender. When I add an environment texture as photo theres also this line, which I'm assuming is the photo meeting together. IS there anyway to make this go away, trying to do a 360 animation and I dont want the line in it.

[image: You can see the line in this photo]

Comment: The image should be able to tile (at least left-right tile), which means it's seamless when placed next to a copy of itself.  Making an image seamlessly tileable is usually done in 2D image software like GIMP or Photoshop, not a 3D program like Blender.  You could search on how to make your image tileable, or you could find an HDRI (they're already left-right seamlessly tileable) and start from there.  https://polyhaven.com/hdris/skies

Comment: you need to fix that in an image editor like Krita or Photoshop, or project on a sphere and in Texture Paint mode use the Clone brush